# How to define types in protractor.conf.js with @ts-check enabled

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, jsdoc

In my Angular CLI v7.3.6 project, I have a `protractor.conf.js` file.  I'd like to enable `@ts-check` in this file in my VSCode.  When `@ts-check` is eanbled, I'd like to call `browser.getCapabilities()` in the `onPrepare()` callback but VSCode said `Unable to find name 'browser'.  ts(2304)`.

The browser should be registered into `Global`. I tried to use `<reference path="..."/>` syntax, but no `browser` has been declared.

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts" />
```

I can't figure out how to declare Global properties with type in a js file (Node.js).

How can I declare `browser`'s type in `protractor.conf.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure out the solution:

1. Add the following comment at first line of the `protractor.conf.js`.

   ```
   // @ts-check
   ```
2. Add the following local variable and **get real value from global**, then assign typing to this local variable.

   ```
   /**
   * @type { import("protractor").ProtractorBrowser }
   */
   let browser = global['browser'];
   ```

Here is the screenshot of the usage:

[image]